# Error 1215 Can't add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I've read several posts on this type of error (one of them was quite similar), but I haven't found one yet that resolves the error that I'm having with the foreign key. Since I can recreate the error, I think I have a pretty good idea of what it is. I am new to SQL, however, and I can't resolve the problem. Here's the code from the two affected tables:

```
create table artist (
     artist_id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
     first_name nvarchar(50) not null,
     last_name nvarchar(50) not null,
     about_artist nvarchar(550) not null,
     start_of_event datetime,
     end_of_event datetime,
     item_id int unsigned not null,
     user_id int unsigned not null,
     last_modified timestamp,
     primary key (artist_id),
     foreign key (item_id) references 
        items (item_id),
    foreign key (user_id) references 
        users (user_id)

 );

 create table items (
     item_id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
     artist_id int unsigned not null,
     item_name nvarchar(50) not null,
     item_description nvarchar(150) not null,
     last_modified timestamp,
     primary key (item_id),
     foreign key (artist_id) references 
        artist(artist_id)
 );
```

My `item_id` is  `item_id int unsigned not null`, in the first table, but `item_id int unsigned not null auto_increment`, in the second table. The second table is the one where it is the primary key. I can't do two auto increments in one table, and if I reverse the order of the tables, the same thing happens with a different column. How can I resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: Artist has a primary key that is a foreign key in items and Items has a primary key that is a foreign key in Artist - feels wrong to me. You could try with a link table (e.g. ArtistItems) which has foreign keys to Artist and Item.

Comment: Are you using `mysql` or `sqlserver`? This seems to me as a many-to-many relationship, so using a bridge table as @MikeP suggests would be the best then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking about my comment, I'm increasingly confident that the link table is the way you need to go.

```
create table artist (
    artist_id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    first_name nvarchar(50) not null,
    last_name nvarchar(50) not null,
    about_artist nvarchar(550) not null,
    start_of_event datetime,
    end_of_event datetime,
    user_id int unsigned not null,
    last_modified timestamp,
    primary key (artist_id),
    foreign key (user_id) references 
        users (user_id)
);

create table items (
    item_id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    artist_id int unsigned not null,
    item_name nvarchar(50) not null,
    item_description nvarchar(150) not null,
    last_modified timestamp,
    primary key (item_id)
);

create table artist_item (
    artist_id int unsigned not null,
    item_id int unsigned not null
    foreign key (artist_id) references
        artist(artist_id),
    foreign key (item_id) references
        items(item_id)
);
```

You could add an auto-increment field to `artist_item`, or have the two ID fields as a composite key.

With this, you can query for all items relating to an artist (e.g. one artist has several items):

```
select
    *
from 
    artist_item join items on 
        artist_item.item_id = items.item_id
where
    artist_item.artist_id = [ID]
```

or all artists related to an item (e.g. one item was worked on by several artists):

```
select
    *
from 
    artist_item join artist on
        artist_item.artist_id = artist.artist_id
where
    artist_item.item_id = [ID]
```

Comment: Thank you. Using MySQL. Adding a linking table that contained both those items worked. I going to read up on linking tables a bit. It looks like they could be really useful in some situations like this.